# Google OAuth Login: Avoid asking the User to choose which account to use

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am relying on Google OAuth to authorize a user for a site I'm building. At the time I'm requesting permission, I already know which Google Account he wants to use (I'm using Google OAuth as a second level auth). However if the User is logged in to several Google Accounts at once, Google redirects the user to a SelectSession interface.

When the user is directed to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?... he ends on https://www.google.com/a/SelectSession. This is unnecessary, because I already know which session he wants to use.

Does anyone know a way to automatically select a specific account, so that the user does not need to manually select the session at https://www.google.com/a/SelectSession?

Comment: @RobW Yeah, but the question is: What is so special about the OP's design, that it won't work to let any user sign in, then access his email address and see "ah, this is xxx@gmail.com"?

Comment: @JanGerlinger The email address is already chosen/given. Now, we only need to verify that the email address indeeds belongs to the user. Any other account is not relevant, hence it's desired that the email address can be selected programatically, in order to reduce the number of user interactions.

Comment: @RobW Yeah, that's obviously already clear to me. But as this is not possible, my intention was to get more background info about the design decisions behind this, to see if there are alternatives to it.

Comment: @JanGerlinger I admit, it's not the most typical use case. But in a situation where I want to give the user a way to link his Google Account to his existing account on my site. I want to avoid having to tell him that he didn't link the correct account and would have to reauthenticate again. I agree though, that OAuth probably doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: @lucasvo Why not let the user connect *any* account he chooses independent of his existing account? That's the way most websites that have such an option handle it.

Comment: Removed my first comment, as it was proved wrong by Steve's answer.

Answer (score 19):

If you already know the user's email address you can add the query parameter user_id= as a hint. If the user is logged in as that account, it'll skip the account selection and go straight to the approval.

It doesn't guarantee the user will actually authorize with that account. Its just a hint and there are still opportunities for them to switch to a different account. If you need to know for sure which account they selected, you'd need to verify that afterwards (e.g. call the userinfo endpoint.)

Comment: Thanks, this user_id= option was the one I'm looking for. I know I can't force it but I'm doing the checks you mentioned anyway. I wanted to solve that user experience issue of making the choice for them.

Comment: By the way, is that documented somewhere on the Google OAuth documentation or is that a standard feature of OAuth? I did not find it in the IETF draft.

Comment: AFAIK its neither standard nor documented. Well, it shows up in various places in our docs (e.g. our Google Drive samples) but not in the OAuth docs.

Comment: I have the opposite requirement. I *always* want to ask them which account to proceed with. I guess I can try tacking on `user_id=<current timestamp>` or something...

Comment: @ThaDon - use prompt=select_account

Comment: @SteveBazyl I'll give that a shot! If you'd like to put that as an answer on my SO question then after I test I'll mark it as the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711665/forcing-a-user-to-choose-an-account-via-google-oauth2?noredirect=1

Comment: @SteveBazyl this doesn't seem to work if i want to avoid the user choosing the account while using the webViewLink and sending an intent to Google Drive

Answer (score -1):

The point of oAuth is that the app doesn't know login/pass, so what you propose is not usable. If you are in a mobile app (you didn't specify), then the credentials will be stored in cookies.

You can delete cookies for user to log in to an account instead of selecting a new account, but for that you should consider signing out from previous account.