# Forcing a user to choose an account via Google OAuth2

Tags: google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I have the following workflow in my application:

1. user logs into my custom app
2. user clicks a button to link their YouTube account
3. application makes a server side request using the code listing below
4. user is redirected to the google auth url

At this point, one of two things happens:

*[I **never** want this behaviour]*
 - If the user is logged into exactly one Google account (i.e. gmail, Google Apps for Domains, etc...) the user is never asked to choose which account to link. It just assumes they want to use the one they are logged into and goes upon its merry way.

*[I **always** want this behaviour]*
 - If the user is either not logged in to any Google accounts, or they are logged in to more than one Google account then they are asked to choose which account they'd like to proceed with.

**Question:** Is there a way for me to force the user to choose an account, even if the user is currently logged into a single Google account?

Code:

```scala
private def getFlow() = {
  if (flow == null) {
    logger.info("Using OAuth client secrets file: " + GoogleOAuthService.CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON)
    clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
      new InputStreamReader(getClass.getResourceAsStream(GoogleOAuthService.CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON)));
    redirectUri = clientSecrets.getDetails().getRedirectUris().get(0)
    flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
      httpTransport, JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(
      dataStoreFactory).setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build()
  }
  flow
}

def newAuthorizationUrl(userId: String) = {
  val urlRequest = getFlow().newAuthorizationUrl()

  urlRequest.setAccessType("offline")
   .setRedirectUri(redirectUri).setState(userId).build()
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384354/force-google-account-chooser

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you can add some parameter in the url to tell google to show the consent screen with the user accounts instead of assuming the default google account.

This can be done by adding `prompt=select_account+consent` ("+" is added as a part of url encoding) in the url.

I did not try this till now but maybe you can try.

Comment: Using the consent options works. It requests to select an account always, even if there's only one signed in.

Answer (score 7):

In the first comment, @Hans gave the correct link to the similar topic. However, if it doesnt help, then here is solution:

just add **`&prompt=consent`** parameter in requesting google's url.