# Force google oauth to prompt user to choose an account

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39859935/24109) you can use the `prompt` querystring to tell google oauth that you'd like the user to choose the user account.

Can someone tell me how to do this in asp.net core - if you're using the `AddGoogle` code as per:

```
.AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = "***";
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "***";
    googleOptions.AccessType = "offline";

    googleOptions.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
    googleOptions.ClaimActions.Clear();
    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "link");
    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
})
```

Comment: The linked dupe has the answer, specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559245/1663001).

Comment: I did - sorry I replied before I saw your comment to the asp.net core response.. just trying that now :)

Comment: YEs agreed - it's a duplicate - apologies !

Answer (score 3):

I've recently had the need to do this too.

Try this:

```
googleOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint += "?prompt=consent";
```

Comment: This will add the consent flow, not account selection.

Comment: Works for me. Their [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#authenticationuriparameters) also mention `prompt=select_account` for account selection.